# scala pattern matching in trait

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

```
sealed trait Option_40to49[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(x) => Some(f(x))
  }
}
```

I work in eclipse, it underlined None with the next error:

```
pattern type is incompatible with expected type; found : None.type required: packageName.Option_40to49[A]
```

and the similar with Some(x)

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : Some[A(in class Some)] required: packageName.Option_40to49[A(in trait Option_40to49)]
```

Why I have this problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `this` in your pattern match you're referring to your `Option_40to49`, but since you haven't implemented `None` or `Some` the compiler doesn't know what these are

Simple versions of these aren't that hard to implement yourself. Note, you'll also want to change your output for `map` to `Option_40to49`

```
sealed trait Option_40to49[+A] {
  def map[B](f: A => B): Option_40to49[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(x) => Some(f(x))
  }
}

case class Some[A](x: A) extends Option_40to49[A]
case object None extends Option_40to49[Nothing]
```